# How can I minimize the distance between 2 values on the x-axis?

Tags: pgfplots

I am totally new to `pgf` plots...

My plot looks like this right now:

[image: My plot looks like this right now:]

How can I minimize the distance between "EOD" und "LOD"?

That is my code:

```
\begin{axis}[height=6cm,
ybar stacked,
ylabel=Anzahl,
xlabel=Serotypen,
xtick={EOD,LOD},
symbolic x coords={EOD,LOD},
legend cell align=left,
enlargelimits={abs=10pt},
legend style={at={(1.4,0.8)},anchor=west},
legend entries={PI-2a, PI-2b, PI-2a und PI-1, PI-2b und PI-1}];
    % 
\addplot table{./Ergebnisse/K_P_1/PI-2a.txt};
\addplot table{./Ergebnisse/K_P_1/PI-2b.txt};
\addplot table{./Ergebnisse/K_P_1/PI-2a1.txt};
\addplot table{./Ergebnisse/K_P_1/PI-2b1.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

How can I generally define the distance between 2 x ticks? E.g. if they are too close?

Each single `*.txt` file looks like this:

```
EOD/LOD Anzahl

EOD 6

LOD 3
```

Comment: Please complete your code to something compilable. Thanks.

Comment: We don't know what your data looks like. But if you are specifying x values in there, you should try `xtick=data` instead of `xtick={EOD,LOD},`.

Comment: I tried the command xtick=data and xtick={EOD,LOD} but nothing changed

Comment: We still don't know everything, as your example stays uncompilable. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't have any x values, `pgfplots` decides for you, where to put the bars. I guess, there is a recommended distance to the sides. Therefore, the first step could be, to reduce the total width of your plot in order to get a nicer look. If you want to keep this size, you may introduce a fixed enlargement to both sides of your x "values". Here, I inserted the TikZ-measure `1`. You may play around with this value and use units such as cm, in, pt... You already hat some enlargement defines. I do not know, if you really need it so I adapted it for the y axis only.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{dummy1.txt}
EOD/LOD Anzahl

EOD 6

LOD 3
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{dummy2.txt}
EOD/LOD Anzahl

EOD 2

LOD 0.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ,height=6cm
    %,width=5cm % you can adapt you total width here, if you like.
    ,ybar stacked
    ,ylabel=Anzahl
    ,xlabel=Serotypen
    ,xtick=data % more flexible, but the same result here.
    ,symbolic x coords={EOD,LOD}
    ,legend cell align=left
    ,enlarge y limits={abs=30pt} % Don't know, if still needed. You can take it away, if you don't need enlargment in y direction.
    ,enlarge x limits=1 % Adapt enlargment to your needs!
    ,legend style={at={(1.4,0.8)},anchor=west}
    ,legend entries={PI-2a, PI-2b, PI-2a und PI-1, PI-2b und PI-1}
    ];
    % 
\addplot table{dummy1.txt}; % you have to change these back to your path!
\addplot table{dummy2.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]